# Where can i find what's inappropriate in Miiverse?

Tags: miiverse

I was trying to post something in Miiverse last night, this was what I had originally wanted to post

> A city on a crab who sunders the earth, 
>   A jet raven who soars the skies, 
>   A demon train bound in flames, 
>   A clockwork spider of many analog eyes, 
>   And a Shinto god in a forest of powerlines.
>
> Out of all 6 Summons, Ziusudra is the only one untouched by the progress of humanity.

However, it kept refusing to post, saying I had used inappropriate words or phrases. After a lot of trial and error, I was able to post it however the only change I made was to change the word `god` to `kami`.

Looking over the Miiverse Code of Conduct, I can't see in there about inappropriate words or phrases and just the word God seems weird to me.

I am wondering if there is a place which details what is inappropriate in Miiverse so I don't have to spend almost an hour trying to work out the one innocent word which is preventing me from posting.

Comment: I came across the "god" thing too the other day. I do wonder why it's "inappropriate".

Answer (score 2):

It seems that your post was flagged as being ***religious*** which is listed along with politics as a form of content not permitted in the [Miiverse Code of Conduct](https://miiverse.nintendo.net/guide/) ([Also found here](http://www.nintendo.com.au/support/help/miiverse-code-of-conduct)).

While there does not appear to be an official list of specific banned words provided by Nintendo there is [confirmation specifically regarding the word "God"](http://www.p4rgaming.com/wii-u-miiverse-banned-words-list-includes-microsoft-sony-and-god/) as well as a few other words. There are several unofficial sources providing other words that are not accepted, but no cohesive collection appears to exist anywhere publicly.